# How to get the total number of marks based on sid?

Tags: arrays, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Input is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "sid": 101,
    "sname": "Rahul",
    "sem": 1,
    "marks": 9
  },
  {
    "sid": 102,
    "sname": "Rahul",
    "sem": 2,
    "marks": 9.5
  },
  {
    "sid": 102,
    "sname": "Rahul",
    "sem": 3,
    "marks": 8
  },
  {
    "sid": 101,
    "sname": "Rahul",
    "sem": 4,
    "marks": 7
  }
]
```

I need to get the total number of marks based on the sid attribute.

Comment: Does [this documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-sumby) provide any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the sid then for each sid sum all the marks.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload 
    groupBy ($.sid) 
    mapObject ($$): sum($.*marks)
```

Output:

```json
{
  "101": 16,
  "102": 17.5
}
```

Note that if you are going to use this information for further processing it will be more efficient to output to application/java instead of JSON.

Alternatively if you prefer to have a list with one element per sid you can use pluck().

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload 
    groupBy ($.sid) 
    pluck { sid: ($$), marksTotal: sum($.*marks) }
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "sid": "101",
    "marksTotal": 16
  },
  {
    "sid": "102",
    "marksTotal": 17.5
  }
]
```